NPM error using npm create amplify@latest -y
I was following the AWS Amplify tutorial, and as I tried npm create npm create amplify@latest -y, this error message popped up:
file:///C:/Users/shaky/expensetracker/node_modules/execa/lib/utils/max-listeners.js:1
import {addAbortListener} from 'node:events';
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:events' does not provide an export named 'addAbortListener'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:541:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

Node.js v18.7.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\shaky\expensetracker
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\shaky\AppData\Local\Temp\npx-99983365.cmd

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shaky\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-30T20_46_04_852Z-debug-0.log

I am new to Node.js and NPM, so I didn't have the slightest idea on how to fix the problem.
I tried downloading the Amplify libraries from the NPM website, but it didn't work.
